# Difference between android terms?

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

I just stuck with one question , what is difference between `"ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI"` and `"ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI"`?

Answer (score -1):

**`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`**

- A data kind representing a telephone number

---

**`ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`**

- Constants for the contacts table, which contains a record per
  aggregate of raw contacts representing the same person.

Comment: what d difference between number of records return by this?

Comment: because i m not getting same number of records with these two

Answer (score -1):

```
android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
```

A data kind representing a telephone number.

```
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
```

content:// can be used to access all data records  CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE MIME type, combined with the associated raw contact and aggregate contact data.

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
```

Constants for the contacts table, which contains a record per aggregate of raw contacts representing the same person. 
you can use update deletion etc in this